# When a cartoon character talks to its creator

Tags: word-request

I was watching Family Guy where the Griffins were stuck in a traffic jam. Peter looks far ahead to see what's going on and he notices that the road hasn't been drawn yet. He looks up and shouts something like, 'Oh come on what are you doing you guys up there?!' The next scene shows the cartoonist falling sleep on his desk; hearing Peter screaming, he wakes up, apologizes and keeps drawing the rest of the road.

Is there a word or phrase for when a cartoon character talks to its creator?

So far I've found 'breaking the fourth wall', but the problem is I see it refers to the character communicating to the audience, not the people backstage.

Comment: What exactly is the question? And how is it related to learning English?

Comment: @VarunNair - It's a word request. The OP wants to know if there is a word for when a cartoon character is communicating with its animators. Moreover, the mention of _the fourth wall_ shows some earnest research has been done.

Comment: My bad. I didn't see the intended question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The informal word used to describe this sort of thing is "meta".

> The cartoon is very meta.
>
> M.C. Escher is so meta.

Colloquial **meta** refers  to acts of self-reference in art and literature; it is a simplified form of the jargon used in literary and art criticism. A play within a play can be called *metadramatic* or *meta-theatrical*.

[image: Escher]

Comment: Thank you very helpful. Based on your answer I found [Metacinema](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacinema). How can refer to the character's behavior. 'Dead Pool', for example, **breaks the fourth wall** several times during the movie. Here for Peter, can I say he **goes meta** during this episode?

Comment: The term when used colloquially is fairly "loose" and could probably be used as you want--  *Peter goes meta*  --  but it's still a bit of a stretch. It's the   cartoonists who "go meta" by having a character, Peter, be aware of their existence and shout something out to them.